# Visualforce - Using Javascript for mandatory fields

Tags: salesforce

Team,

I am working on a Salesforce Visualforce page using Javascript to validate mandatory fields - both picklist and text fields. I tried using html *required = true* but that won't work because I have two functionalities - save link and submit button - on my visualforce page. I would like the user to get an error if they try to submit and the required fields are null/blank. Below is my code but it's not working.

```js
<script>
 function submitOnClick(objSubmitBtn){
  var RevPL = document.getElementById('RevPL').value;
  if(RevPL == null || RevPL == ''){
   alert('Review needed.')
   return false;
  }

  var StatusPL = document.getElementById('StatusPL').value;
  if(StatusPL == null || AdhStatusPL == ''){
   alert('Status needed.')
  }
  
  var StatusPL = document.getElementById('Notes').value;
  if(StatusPL == null || AdhStatusPL == ''){
   alert('Please add notes.')
  }

  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')){
   objSubmitBtn.disabled = true;
   objSubmitBtn.value = 'Submitting... Please Wait';
   doSubmit();
  }
 }
</script>

<apex:form id="PRDetails"> 
 <table width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td width="50%">
    3. Review of documentation &nbsp;
     <b> <apex:outputText value="{!PR['Review__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']='Complete'}"/> </b>
      <apex:inputField value="{!PR['Review__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']!='Complete'}" id="RevPL" />
    
   </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
 
 <br/>  
 
 <table width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td width="50%">4. Status &nbsp;
    <b> <apex:outputText value="{!PR['Status__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']='Complete'}"                                      /></b>
     <apex:inputField value="{!PR['Status__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']!='Complete'}" id="StatusPL" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="padding">Notes:</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="padding">
    <b> <apex:outputText value="{!PR['Notes__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']='Complete'}"/> </b>
     <apex:inputField styleClass="inputLTextbox" value="{!PR['Notes__c']}" rendered="{!PR['Status__c']!='Complete'}" id="Notes"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!PR}" var="PR">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" style="background: #1895c1; color: #FFFFFF; width: 150px;" onclick="submitOnClick(this);" rendered="{!PR['Status__c'] !='Complete'}"/> 
                </apex:repeat>
                <apex:actionFunction name="doSubmit" action="{!submitPR}" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><apex:commandLink action="{!savePR}" value="Save" id="SaveLink" style="text-decoration:none; color:blue;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You've got

```
var StatusPL
```

Declated twice.

2) Visualforce generates IDs in it's own way (adds hierarchy to it) - your "getElementById" won't work, you need to do something else - do an inspect on your page in browser. Maybe add classes and use getElementByClass instead?